# Hide Objective C in mixed Swift Cocoapod library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, module-map

I am developing a Swift Cocoapod library which actually is a wrapper around some Objective C code.
My goal is to expose only the Swift part of the library, while making the Objective C
as private as possible. However, as the Swift part is a wrapper around the Objective C code, it needs to access it, although just internally.

I have searched and tried various approaches, but none of them worked at all.

---

First, I tried to address it via the use of a *modulemap* file. The idea was to create a Swift module called something like `MyLibrary` containing all the Swift code, while the Objective C code would be on the `MyLibrary.Private` module (I know the module would still be accessible, but this separation would be enough for me). The *modulemap* would look something like:

```
//MyLibrary.modulemap

framework module MyLibrary {
    module Private {
        header "MyObjectiveC.h"
        export *
    }
}
```

And adding the following line in the `MyLibrary.podspec` file

```
s.module_map = 'path/to/MyLibrary.modulemap'
```

However, by using this approach, even if I only import the `MyLibrary` module would still get access to all the Objective C classes, without having to import the `MyLibrary.Private` module to do so.

---

A second approach I tried was to make use of a *private.modulemap* file. So I would end up with two different *modulemap* files:

```
//MyLibrary.modulemap

framework module MyLibrary {}
```

```
//MyLibrary.private.modulemap

module MyLibrary.Private {
    header "MyObjectiveC.h"
    export *
}
```

I would then add the following line in the `MyLibrary.podspec` file

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'MODULEMAP_PRIVATE_FILE' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/MyLibrary/path/to/MyLibrary.private.modulemap' }
```

However, I get a failed build stating that it can not find the `MyLibrary.Private` module.

---

Is there anything I am doing wrong in these approaches? Or is there any other way to allow my library's Swift classes access the Objective C classes privately without exposing those, at least explicitly, requiring to import an specific `*.Private` module for it?

Comment: What a problem just to not expose objc's headers?

Comment: @Cy-4AH As the Swift part of the library is a wrapper around the Objective C code, I need to access the ObjC from Swift (I've edited the question to make it clearer now).
Is there a way I could access the ObjC code from the Swift one, but without exposing the headers externally?